# linking multiple mysql tables by the same id

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to do a website where there will be a list of suppliers and clicking on the supplier will show the data of that particular supplier on another page. Currently I am only able to do it with one database.

Is it possible to link multiple database as the other database have other supplier's data such as purchase records?

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; 
 $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM my30_rsl WHERE id = $id");
?>
```

Let say I want to link another database:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM bought WHERE id = $id");
```

Note the:
The table structure for both database is similar where SupplierName and Company data are the same

[image: my30_rsl]
[image: bought]

Comment: Yes, you can join multiple tables, look into https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html and many tutorials out there. Just Google "how to join tables in mysql"; you can add "php" to that also. Edit: Here's one: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/ which I enjoy reading myself; it's a good site.

Comment: You should also look into using a prepared statement. Your present code if you didn't know, is open to an SQL injection. Or, add `(int)` to your GET array assignment if it's to always be an integer.